How to count the number of words in WordList[] that starts with "q"
This question is from the "Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language", when dealing with the String and Text. I think there must be easier ways to solve this. Would you guys give me some enlightenment?
I am expecting to solve this problem with the basic functions. Without the Select[] or some sort like this.

This is exercise 11.13 from https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/3rd-ed/11-strings-and-text.html

It just needs a little bit concentration to solve this. I made it!
Count[StringTake[WordList[Language->"English"],1],"q"]

Anyway, this marks the my first question and answer in stackoverflow.

Please note there is a dedicated Mathematica StackExchange site should you wish to try your hand on some more Q&As : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/
